# MySQL DATE_ADD doesn't select data

Tags: mysql, sql-timestamp

```
| id | title     |     start          |
| 1  | smth      | 2017-09-23 12:24:00|
```

I need to select the row where start   =  current date + 3 days.

Let's presume that current date is 2017 Sept 23.

My query is :

```
select * from db where db.start = DATE_ADD(curdate(), interval 3 day);
```

The query is running but gives no result. I am definitely sure that there is one row that corresponds select parameters. What is wrong with my query?

Comment: the time is probably not the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from db where DATE(db.start) = DATE_ADD(curdate(), interval 3 day);
```